# Menu hamburguesa ¿Como puedo hacerlo responsive y corregir los problemas que tengo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mi idea es hacer un botón hamburguesa con desplazamiento horizontal y que sea responsive.
Actualmente tengo esto, no tengo muchos conocimientos, por eso me gustaría saber si alguien me puede dar una mano con este menú. Quiero que el menu se abra con el icono de hamburguesa, hacia la derecha y cuando ya este abierto el menu, con el mismo icono hamburguesa  haciendo click en el o otra parte de la pagina se cierre. Esto seria para cuando la pagina esta siendo vista en un ordenador o notebook.

Cuando sea visto de un dispositivo pequeño sea el tipico icono hamburguesa que despliega hacia abajo

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: auto;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: block;
}

.sidenav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    transition: 0.5s;

}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1; 

}

@media (max-width: 4000px){
.sidenav .row{
    height: 60px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
.sidenav .row{
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: center;
}
}
.sidenav {
height: auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- boostrap-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/personalstyle.css">  <!--estilo personal -->


<span style="font-size:25px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; MENU</span>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav row">
 <div class="col-md-2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&#9776;MENU</a></div>
 <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#servicesection">SERVICIOS</a></div>
 <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#clientessection">CLIENTES</a></div>
 <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#biografiasection">BIO</a></div>
 <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#contactosection">CONTACTO</a></div>
 <div class="col-md-2"><a href="Index/EN.html">English</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedo ayudarte si te explicas de mejor manera , que quieres lograr específicamente?

Comment: Pretendes que se abra y se cierre con el mismo botón?

Answer (score 1):

Te puedo recomendar alinear el `botón` que abre la navegación a la derecha y cambiar el comportamiento a:

- Abrir el menú con el `botón` hamburguesa.
- Cerrar el menú si el usuario hace clic fuera del menú.

Para esto, como en aplicaciones `Android`, usualmente con `Material Design`, al abrir el menú el contenido por debajo se oscurece, y cuando el usuario hace un `touch` fuera del área del menú se cierra este.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo.

```js
    var menu      = document.querySelector('#menu');
    var drawer    = document.querySelector('nav');
    var oscurecer = document.querySelector('.oscurecer');

    menu.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        /*Abrir menu*/
        drawer.classList.toggle('open');

        /* Oscurecer contenido al abrir el menu */
        oscurecer.style.display = 'block';

        /*Evitar que se haga scroll*/
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    oscurecer.addEventListener('click', function () {
        /* Cerrar menu */
        drawer.classList.remove('open');

        /* Aclarar contenido al cerrar el menu */
        oscurecer.style.display = 'none';
        
        /*Activar scroll*/
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.overflow = "auto";
    });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
  color: #212121;
}
a:visited {
  color: #212121;
}

.menu-mobile {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 72px;
    padding:0 2em;
    background-color: #4d2b90;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.blanco{
  color:white;
}
/*Esta clase se aplica para oscurecer toda la pantalla por debajo del nav*/
.oscurecer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
nav {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    transform: translate(-300px, 0);
    transition: transform .3s ease;
}
/*Cuando se agrega esta clase el nav aparecerá*/
nav.open {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

/*Algo estilo a los item del menu*/
nav li {
    padding: 1em;
}
nav li a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #424242;
}
```

```html
<!--Oscurecerá la pantalla por debajo de la navegación al abrirse-->
<div class="oscurecer"></div>
<!--Zona visible al usuario con ícono-->
<div class="menu-mobile">
    <div>
      <span class="blanco">Página</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="menu">
      <i class="material-icons blanco">menu</i>
    </a>
</div>
 
<nav>
  <li><a href="#Inicio">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Acerca">Acerca de</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
</nav>
```

Comment: Has respondido a la pregunta sin saber exactamente qué quiere el usuario, de todos modos lo que más pretendía el usuario era abrir y cerrar el menú con un mismo botón (con la hamburguesa) , y también se puede añadir una función aparte para cerrarlo si se toca fuera de éste.

Answer (score 0):

Primero añade una clase cuando el menú debe estar abierto de la cual te puedas colgar. Creo que es mejor ponerla en un elemento de jerarquía muy superior como el body porque así puedes lanzar otras cosas relacionadas a ese evento que no necesariamente estén al nivel del elemento que estés manipulando. Como por ejemplo cambiar el color del footer cuando el menú está abierto.

Para eso mejor utiliza scripts externos en lugar de en tus atributos como onclick, se me hace mejor práctica.

Para la posición del elemento es mejor utilizar transforms en lugar de cambiar el width o height de 0 a la medida requerida porque eso puede deformar los elementos interiores y desde el punto de vista estético se vé horrible

Finalmente al html agrega un elemento extra que servirá como fondo clickeable para cerrarlo `mySidenavBackground` esto implica que tengas que añadir un contenedor adicional para los elementos del menú `mySidenavContainer`

```js
var sidenavIcon = document.getElementById('mySIdenavIcon');
var sidenav = document.getElementById('mySidenav');

sidenavIcon.addEventListener('click', function(){
 if( document.body.classList.contains('mySidenav_open') ) {
  document.body.classList.remove('mySidenav_open');
 } else {
  document.body.classList.add('mySidenav_open');
 }
});

document.getElementById('mySidenavBackground').addEventListener('click', function(){
 document.body.classList.remove('mySidenav_open');
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(1, -0.05, 0.2, 1);
}
@media (min-width: 401px) {
  .sidenav {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidenav {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.sidenav .mySidenavContainer {
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
}
.sidenav #mySidenavBackground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  opacity: 0;
}
.mySidenav_open .sidenav #mySidenavBackground {
  transition: opacity 0.25s linear 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.mySidenav_open .sidenav {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.sidenav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.sidenav a:hover, .sidenav a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#mySIdenavIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: gray;
}
#mySIdenavIcon:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<span id="mySIdenavIcon">&#9776; MENU</span>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav row">
 <div class="mySidenavContainer">
  <div class="col-md-2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&#9776;MENU</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#servicesection">SERVICIOS</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#clientessection">CLIENTES</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#biografiasection">BIO</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#contactosection">CONTACTO</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"><a href="Index/EN.html">English</a></div>
 </div>
 <span id="mySidenavBackground"></span>
</div>
```